# Android keeps the soft keyboard showing when enter done button

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

I am developing an Android app and need user to input the password. When the user press done or enter button, the soft keyboard will disappear.
When the password is wrong and I want soft keyboard still on the screen without shaking. Because my solution now is let it disappear and bring it on the screen again, keyboard shaking will occur and I think it is bad design.
So the question is how can I keep the soft keyboard showing on the screen all the time even the user press enter button?

Answer (score 1):

your Password edittext like this

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

java code for check password.
Example : password id 12345

```
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        boolean handled = false;
                        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                            if (v.getText().toString().equals("12345")) {
                           // if the pass word is 12345
                               // hide your keyboard code
                                Log.e("!_@@ ", "true");
                            } else {
                   // if password is not 12345
                       // not hide keyboard code
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
                                Log.e("!_@@ ", "false");
                            }
                            handled = true;
                        }
                        return handled;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I have wrote the code similar to your solution, but I think it did not solve my question, my question is how can I keep the soft keyboard showing when the password is not 12345.